# Having a problem detecting which channel a message has come from in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm currently developing a discord bot for chess that can host games between people regardless of which servers they are in or if one or both are playing in DMs with the bot. I'm currently having a problem with this section of code:

```
    pl1 = player(plId1, plChannel1, plWebhook1)
    pl2 = player(plId2, plChannel2, plWebhook2)
    ##Picking piece colours
    await pl1.channel.send("Established Connection to the other player. \n\nTo begin, please message either `|White` or `|Black` to declare who will be playing each colour.")
    await pl2.channel.send("Established Connection to the other player. \n\nTo begin, please message either `|White` or `|Black` to declare who will be playing each colour.")
    c1 = None
    c2 = None
    while pl1.piece == None:
        message = await bot.wait_for('message')
        if message.channel == pl1.channel:
            await forward(message.content, pl1, pl2)
            if message.content.lower() == '|white' and c1 == None:
                await pl1.channel.send(f'{pl1.name} has chosen to play as White')
                await pl2.channel.send(f'{pl1.name} has chosen to play as White')
                c1 = True
            elif message.content.lower() == '|black' and c1 == None:
                await pl1.channel.send(f'{pl1.name} has chosen to play as Black')
                await pl2.channel.send(f'{pl1.name} has chosen to play as Black')
                c1 = False
        elif message.channel == pl2.channel:
            await forward(message.content, pl2, pl1)
            if message.content.lower() == '|white' and c2 == None:
                await pl1.channel.send(f'{pl2.name} has chosen to play as White')
                await pl2.channel.send(f'{pl2.name} has chosen to play as White')
                c2 = True
            elif message.content.lower() == '|black' and c2 == None:
                await pl1.channel.send(f'{pl2.name} has chosen to play as Black')
                await pl2.channel.send(f'{pl2.name} has chosen to play as Black')
                c2 = False
        if c1 != None and c2 != None:
            #some more code here that sets pl1.piece among other things
```

What is meant to happen is that each player can select their colour once before the bot proceeds to the section of code after this. This works just fine for pl1; by dming the bot they can set their colour and their message is passed on to pl2 as well, as intended using the forward function. However, if pl2 messages the bot, the bot doesn't react at all, other than the typical 'command white not found' or 'command black not found' errors in the code, which happens because the functions |white and |black aren't defined for the bot as a whole (which is perfectly fine, these come up whenever an invalid command is entered by anyone anywhere).

I could do with a hand on how to solve this fairly fast as I have a deadline to keep to. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try print debugging. i.e inside the if statement, print 'player 2 has sent this` or something, make sure it works. I don't see any errors here

Comment: @Ceres I don't know why I hadn't thought of this, but upon trying print debugging to see which channel I was sending to I found that pl2.channel was just {user} and the channel sent from was 'Direct message with {user}'. Why this is different I do not know, but at least I found out that it was. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that pl2.channel was just the user while the channel I was reading was 'Direct message from {user}'. I hadn't thought that they'd be different, considering that sending to either of them yields the same result. Thanks to @Ceres for reminding me that print debugging is a thing; it had completely slipped my mind to try it considering I was dealing with objects that I didn't think would print well.